# Rails sign out Devise user from subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, csrf

I have an application that separates controllers based on whether the request includes a subdomain or not. Devise is scoped to be accessed from the main domain, i.e `lvh.me:5000/login`. Upon a successful login, a customer is redirected to their "store" which lives on a subdomain, `customer-store-name.lvh.me:5000` - here they can access routes particular to their account, but can not access routes scoped to the main domain, like marketing pages or the Devise routes.

On `customer-store-name.lvh.me:5000` I have a dropdown menu that includes a Sign Out link,

```
= link_to 'Sign out',
  destroy_user_session_url(host: "lvh.me", subdomain: nil),
  method: :delete
```

This fails to sign out the user, resulting in a `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`
 error. Below is the output that further explains that the `HTTP Origin header (http://customer-store-name.lvh.me:5000) didn't match request.base_url`.

```
13:37:59 web.1      | Started DELETE "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-17 13:37:59 -0400
13:37:59 web.1      | Processing by Users::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
13:37:59 web.1      |   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2 /*application:Example*/  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
13:37:59 web.1      | HTTP Origin header (http://customer-store-name.lvh.me:5000) didn't match request.base_url (http://lvh.me:5000)
13:37:59 web.1      | Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 2090)
```

The issue only persists on sign out; I've ruled out the `session_store` as it is configured properly and works on sign up. However, I reckon it works because `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` and `RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` redirect to the customers subdomain, and here I am trying to directly make a cross-origin request. I'm curious how others have handled sign out with Devise on subdomains in Rails.

```
cache_servers = ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/0" }

Rails.application.config.session_store :cache_store,
  key: '_example_session',
  serializer: :json,
  domain: '.lvh.me',
  samesite: 'lax',
  redis: {
    expire_after: 1.week,
    key_prefix: 'example:session:',
    url: cache_servers
}
```

Comment: This really does not have anything to do with Devise per say. Rather its just the Rails anti-CSRF protection thats preventing a cross site request. Check the CRSF token passed in the request body against the value in the session. https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef

Comment: Ah. Thanks @max. Yeah I was unsure if Devise was handled the request at all, or if it is a strict anti-CSRF mechanism. In the `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` can I disable that with `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true, except: :destroy`, or will that introduce other vulnerabilities?

Comment: You can use [`skip_forgery_protection`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_forgery_protection) to skip it on a single action. If your skipping it on the destroy action its not really that vulnerable. There is nothing for an attacker to gain by a user logging out of the system - logins are a totally different story. There could be something I'm missing though. Its pretty late.